# How to convert and show Seconds into Years,Months,Days using custom pipe in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am getting seconds (validity) by API calling and I need to show it in terms of Years,Months,Days in frontEnd...
How can I show it using custom Pipe or other way?

I have created a custom pipe, but how can I return the values?

```
 export class SecondsToDaysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(val: number): number {
       let totalSeconds = val;
      }
  }
```

Expected: Validity: 01 year 03 months 03 days

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to `return` a value to get the pipe working. See https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes for more information.

Comment: thnx,how can I return years,months and days after calculation? @Roy

Answer (score 5):

You can use moment and moment-duration-format library.
install both library by following command

```
npm install moment --save
npm install moment-duration-format --save
```

also add types to use it in angular

```
npm i @types/moment-duration-format --save
```

After installation, create pipe like below,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';

@Pipe({
  name: 'secondToYearMonthDays'
})
export class SecondToYearMonthDaysPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return moment.duration(value, 'seconds').format('Y [years]: M [months]: D [days]');
  }

}
```

and use this pipe in html

```
<label>{{72650000| secondToYearMonthDays}}</label>
 Output : 2 years: 3 months: 19 days
```

You can also make this pipe more generic for different time units and display format by passing arguments with pipe name.

You can checkout supported format here : https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format